# Django sitemap error - TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django, django-templates, sitemap

I've got error with django sitemap view.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /sitemap.xml
sitemap_index.xml
```

Probably something wrong with template loaders, but I can't figure out what exactly.

There is my TEMPLATE config:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ],
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: what's your project structure ?

Comment: @dnit13 Separate apps for each entity in project. All apps added to INSTALLED_APPS. What exactly you mean under 'project structure'?

Comment: I guess he meant the structure of project and apps, the folders hierarchy, where is located sitemap.xml for example?

Comment: As i understand template locates here:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates/sitemap.xml

I make fix by adding copies of these templates [link](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates) in app 'templates' directory. But still want to solve this issue..

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you have this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    ...
]
```